# Subspace of $C^1 [0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

Consider the inner product space of continuously diﬀerentiable functions, $C^1 [0,1]$ with inner product:$$\left<f,g\right> =\int_{0}^1f(x)\overline{g(x)}\,dx + \int_{0}^1f'(x)\overline{g'(x)}\,dx $$

1. Show $\left<f,\cosh\right> = f(1)\sinh(1)$ for any $f$ $\in$ $C^1 [0,1]$
2. Use part 1. to show the subspace:$$\{f\in C^1 [0,1]:f(1)=0\}$$ is a closed subspace of $C^1 [0,1]$

   I can do part 1. but can't get part 2. I think I have to show that every convergent sequence in that subspace has its limit in that subspace. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $\{\cosh\}^{\perp}$.

> $\langle f, \cosh \rangle = 0 \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad f(1) = 0$.

Comment: Looking at your hint my suggested solution would be along the following lines: $$\{cosh\}^{\bot}=\{f\in C^1 [0,1]:f(1)=0\}$$ as $$\left<f,\cosh\right>\Longleftrightarrow f(1)=0$$ Therefore as $\{cosh\}$ is closed, $\{cosh\}^{\bot}=\{f\in C^1 [0,1]:f(1)=0\}$ is closed. Does this sound right?

Comment: $A^{\perp}$ is closed for *any* subset $A$, hence closedness of $\{\cosh\}$ is not needed. Everything else is right.

Comment: Thanks very much. I think I understand this sort of material much better now!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Integrate by parts
$$
\int_0^1f'(t)\sinh(t)\,\mathrm{d}t
$$